# What are the OS X equivalents for Windows shortcuts in Citrix Receiver?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, citrix

On Windows, it's `Ctrl + F2` and `Ctrl + F1` which disable full screen in Citrix and send `Ctrl-Alt-Del`.

How do I enter these commands on a Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! seems pressing CTRL + Option brings up the menu bar and the dock.. which is what I really wanted i.e. to get out of citrix.

Pressing Ctrl + Option + Fn + Delete does send the windows CTRL + ALT + DEL.